# Azure AD generates wrong SAML metadata for multi-tenant app

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I have created a registration in Azure AD via the portal in the Enterprise applications blade.

I then switched to App registrations blade -> Authentication and set the app to multi-tenant.

Next I switched back to Enterprise blade -> Single sign-on and set up  SAML configuration to point to our SAML2 SP (Shibboleth).

But when I attempt to sign on to our service with a user from a foreign tenant, I get an error saying to please add user as guest.

This is because the SingleSignOnService in the IdP metadata that Azure AD generates is wrong. It points at the tenant-specific endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/saml2`) instead of `/common`.

How can I get AAD to generate correct metadata for a multi-tenant app? This Microsoft guide seems to suggest that it should be possible to create a multi-tenant SAML2 app:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing

Comment: Try to specify the `Sign on URL` in `Single Sign-On -> Basic SAML Configuration` with `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/saml2`.

Comment: That unfortunately did not have any effect on the generated SAML2 metadata.

Comment: Hello @SørenBoisen Just wanted to check if you have followed the 4 steps mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant  to convert the app to multitenant.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the **tenant-independent** endpoint. In this endpoint address, common appears instead of a tenant domain name or ID: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-saml-protocol-reference